# Generic class uses generic argument

Tags: java, generics

## Situation

I am making a graph class that looks like this:

```
class ImmutableGraph<G> {
    Node<G> selectedNode;
    private ImmutableGraph(Node<G> initialNode) { selectedNode = initialNode; }

    //many more things
}
```

and I'm currently using a (nested) builder class like so

```
public static class GraphBuilder<B> {
    Node<B> currentNode;
    public GraphBuilder(B value){ currentNode = new Node(value); }
    public ImmutableGraph<B> build(){
        return new ImmutableGraph<B>(currentNode);
    }

    //many more things
}
```

which uses the (nested) node class

```
private static class Node<N> {
    private final N value;
    Array<Nodes<N>> neighbours;
    public Node(N v){ value = v; }

    //many more things
}
```

## Problem

I can't find a way to instantiate my `ImmutableGraph` using my builder because the return type is not correct.  Indeed, compilation suggests that `GraphBuilder.build()` should return a type `ImmutableGraph<Node<B>>` and not `ImmutableGraph<B>`

For now the only solution I found is to change the return type to `ImmutableGraph<Node<B>>` but that's feels dumb since all graphs (except empty ones) are graphs of nodes. The `Node` type is also confusing since the user never interacts with it.

edit:

- corrected the "new" in the factory method of the builder

Comment: This sounds like it should work as you described, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to nest these classes to get it to compile so I can play with it.  Could you post all three classes organized the way you would like in one code block?

Comment: There is not just a `new` missing im the `build` method?

Comment: @Jessie here is the whole thing: http://pastebin.com/tu9YeSXR the return type of the builder was another builder and not an ImmutableGraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your build method should `return new ImmutableGraph<B>(currentNode);`

```
import java.util.List;

public class ImmutableGraph<G> {
Node<G> selectedNode;

private ImmutableGraph(Node<G> initialNode) {
    selectedNode = initialNode;
}

// many more things

public static class GraphBuilder<B> {
    Node<B> currentNode;

    public GraphBuilder(B value) {
        currentNode = new Node<B>(value);
    }

    public ImmutableGraph<B> build() {
        return new ImmutableGraph<B>(currentNode);
    }

    // many more things
}

private static class Node<N> {
    private final N value;
    List<Node<N>> neighbours;

    public Node(N v) {
        value = v;
    }

    // many more things
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphBuilder<Integer> builder = new GraphBuilder<Integer>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    ImmutableGraph<Integer> graph = builder.build();
    System.out.println(graph.selectedNode.value);
}
}
```